# I need to compare 2 tables in MySql and dispaly the differences

Tags: mysql, sql, service

both tables table_a and table_b has to be compared using employee_id column which is present in both of them.
Both Tables have **MILLIONS** of rows.
3 Results must be displayed-

1. employee_id present in table_a but not present in table_b.
2. vice-versa.
3. there would be case when a particular employee_id is present in both tables but the data in other columns for that employee_id might not be same in both tables. These rows must also be displayed showing the columns where there is data mismatch.

*Since there are millions of rows in both tables, the process must be fast so that both tables can be compared quickly.*
I am using MySQL server to write query.

Comment: You're lucky, MySQL is quite fast...

Comment: Take a look at https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/compare-and-sync-tables-tom-kyte-and-group-by? The approach is union the tables, for all columns you want to compare plus two columns to show which of the source tables the row is from, then summarise this by the columns you are comparing, and find where the number of occurences differs between the two tables. The advantage is each table is scanned just once. You might also find that including the colums you are comparing in an index speeds things up.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Dohnal the question is that I need the MySQL query for the 3 results that is to be displayed. Either it can be 3 queries for the 3 results or a single query to represent the 3 results combined.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky, but here is an example assuming that `employee_id` is unique in each table:

```
select employee_id,
       (case when max(which) = 'a' then 'A-only'
             when min(which) = 'b' then 'B-only'
             else 'both'
        end) as which,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when count(*) = 2 and not min(col1) <=> max(col1) then 'col1' end),
                 (case when count(*) = 2 and not min(col2) <=> max(col2) then 'col2' end)
                ) as differences
from ((select 'a' as which, employee_id, col1, col2
       from a
      ) union all
      (select 'b' as which, employee_id, col1, col2
       from b
      )
     ) ab
group by employee_id;
```

Note that this uses the `NULL`-safe comparison operator.